# Laravel: Attempt to assign property "key" on null

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I want to save data to my SQL table using a join. I have 3 tables. `vehicle`, `smsstaff` and `vehicleslog`. `vehicle` and `smsstaff` join to `vehicleslog` so I can get the name of cars and staff members to the their dropdown lists. It then stores the IDs of the corresponding name in the `vehicleslog` table and returns the name in the index:

VehicleLog Model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class VehicleLog extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'vehicleslog';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $dates = ['date'];
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    
    use HasFactory;
}
```

Maintenance controller:

```
class MaintenanceController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {

        // $energy = Maintenance::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(5);
        $energy = VehicleLog::join('vehicle', 'vehicleslog.vehicle_id', '=', 'vehicle.id')    
        ->join('smsstaff', 'vehicleslog.smsstaff_key', '=', 'smsstaff.smsstaff_key')
        ->get();
        $cars = Vehicle::get();
        $staff = Staff::all();
        return view('admin.vmaintenance', compact('energy', 'cars', 'staff'));
    }
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        // $energy = new Maintenance;
        $energy = VehicleLog::join('vehicle', 'vehicleslog.vehicle_id', '=', 'vehicle.id')
        ->join('smsstaff', 'vehicleslog.smsstaff_key', '=', 'smsstaff.smsstaff_key')
        ->first();
        $cars = Vehicle::all();
        $staff = Staff::get();
        $energy->smsstaff_key = $request->input('smsstaff_key');
        $energy->vehicle_id = $request->input('vehicle_id');
        $energy->log_dt = $request->input('log_dt');
        $energy->admin_time = $request->input('admin_time');
        $energy->driving_time = $request->input('driving_time');
        $energy->work_time = $request->input('work_time');
        $energy->jobcard_count = $request->input('jobcard_count');
        $energy->start_odo = $request->input('start_odo');
        $energy->end_odo = $request->input('end_odo');


        $energy->save();
        return redirect('/vmaintenance')->with('success', 'data added');
    }
}
```

view:

```
   <div>  
                <label>Select Staff</label>
                <select name="smsstaff_key" >
                    @foreach($staff as $staffs)
                    <option value="{{ $staffs->smstaff_key }}">{{ $staffs['name'] }}</option>
            @endforeach
                </select>
              </div>
              <div>
```

When adding a vehicle, it works well but the adding of staff through the drop down returns a, `"Attempt to assign property "smsstaff_key" on null"`

Comment: `$energy` is null, Check the query. You should always check if a variable is not null before you try to change it.

Comment: @GertB. Should I make it not null?

Comment: Depends on the functionality you want. now you try to edit a existing `VehicleLog, but it's not found in your db.

Comment: I made it not null but its still giving the same error @GertB.

Comment: How did you "make it not null"? If you get the error  "Attempt to assign property "smsstaff_key" on null" it is null.

Comment: @GertB. Okay now I am confused. Sorry about that. Okay the situation I have is if I remove the smsstaff Join, the vehicle join works and it stores well. only when the staff join is put, thats when the index shows nothings and it does not add because of the null

Comment: You could make things a lot easier if you use Eloquent relations instead of manually joining in your query. if you want to keep the custom join take a look at what left, right and inner joins do.

Comment: how would I use the eloquent relations?

Comment: docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: @GertB. this may confuse me more. Is there a way to use a join twice on the same variable for 2 tables? I looked at the query builder laravel page which gave me this code but it still wont budge

Comment: can you put a dd($energy) right after you assign your $energy to see its null or not in your store method?

Comment: @soroushganjooe in the controller or view?

Comment: in your controller , ibelive you cant find the model in first place so its null

Comment: @soroushganjooe, sorry i have never used dd before, where about would it go?

Comment: public function store(Request $request)
    {

        // $energy = new Maintenance;
        $energy = VehicleLog::join('vehicle', 'vehicleslog.vehicle_id', '=', 'vehicle.id')
        ->join('smsstaff', 'vehicleslog.smsstaff_key', '=', 'smsstaff.smsstaff_key')
        ->first();     //here     dd($energy);

Comment: @soroushganjooe It returns a null on the screen, thats all

Comment: ok ,so you cant find a data , and you want update that...so its returns an error... now i have question... you just want to add a record in your vehicle log table in your database?

Comment: no data on other tables?

Comment: @soroushganjooe yes I want to add a record but the data to add needs to be pulled from my `smsstaff` table to the `vehicleslog` table

Comment: @soroushganjooe correct. the other tables are just to get data from

Comment: in your code your getting all your datas from your request (your form); witch ones are getting from other tables?

Comment: vehicle and staff are the only ones coming from other tables @soroushganjooe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dont sure its work but try :

```
  public function store(Request $request)
{
$energy= new  VehicleLog();

   //  $energy->YOURE VehicleLog COLUMNS = THE DATA to BE STORE IN  COLUMN

    $energy->smsstaff_key = $request->input('smsstaff_key');
    $energy->vehicle_id = $request->input('vehicle_id');
    $energy->log_dt = $request->input('log_dt');
    $energy->admin_time = $request->input('admin_time');
    $energy->driving_time = $request->input('driving_time');
    $energy->work_time = $request->input('work_time');
    $energy->jobcard_count = $request->input('jobcard_count');
    $energy->start_odo = $request->input('start_odo');
    $energy->end_odo = $request->input('end_odo');


    $energy->save();
```

Comment: how would that look?

Comment: I have not tried it, @souroushganjooe, Im not quite sure what to replace the comment with. like the syntax

Comment: do not replace any thing..its just for better understanding

Comment: just remove yore join query and add  $energy= new  VehicleLog(); insted...

Comment: just check your database to see if all your columns is filled; if not just work on getting your data from your form or other tables

Answer (score 0):

thats a simple answer i know..but maybe the problem is your "smstaff_key" spelling in your option :

```
                    <option value="{{ $staffs->smstaff_key }}">{{ 
                   $staffs['name'] }}</option>
```

and it shlod be :

```
                    <option value="{{ $staffs->smsstaff_key }}">{{ $staffs['name'] }}</option>
```